# Combine multiple function in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, zurb-foundation

I am making a tab pills for mo filter using zurb foundation.

Is it possible to combine this? I would like to use only 1 function because they are just almost the same just the variable is changing. Is it possible to make it more dynamic. I think .val() is not compatible with definition list.

```
<dl class="tabs pill">
  <dd class="active"><a class="allTab" href='#'>ALL</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="Tab1" href="#">filter1</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="Tab2" href="#">filter2</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="Tab3" href="#">filter3</a></dd> 
</dl>
```

JS:

```
$('.tab1').live('click',function(){
  var dis = $(this);
  var str= "filter1";
    $('#searchForm1').ajaxSubmit({
      type: 'get',
        url: '/sample/search?str='+str,
        beforeSend:function(){
          dis.text('Filtering...');
            dis.css({"font-size":"11px"});    
        },
        success:function(html){
          $('.sample').html(html);
              dis.text('filter1');
                dis.css({"font-size":"14px"});
        },
        error:function() {
          alert('Network Error..Please try again.');
        }
  });
});
$('.tab2').live('click',function(){
  var dis = $(this);
  var str= "filter2";
    $('#searchForm1').ajaxSubmit({
      type: 'get',
        url: '/sample/search?str='+str,
        beforeSend:function(){
          dis.text('Filtering...');
            dis.css({"font-size":"11px"});
        },
        success:function(html){
          $('.sample').html(html);
              dis.text('filter2');
                dis.css({"font-size":"14px"});
        },
        error:function() {
          alert('Network Error..Please try again.');
        }
  });
}); 
$('.tab3').live('click',function(){
  var dis = $(this);
  var str= "filter3";
    $('#searchForm1').ajaxSubmit({
      type: 'get',
        url: '/sample/search?str='+str,
        beforeSend:function(){
          dis.text('Filtering...');
            dis.css({"font-size":"11px"});
        },
        success:function(html){
          $('.sample').html(html);
              dis.text('filter3');
                dis.css({"font-size":"14px"});
        },
        error:function() {
          alert('Network Error..Please try again.');
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: This question sounds like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<dl class="tabs pill">
   <dd class="active"><a class="allTab" href='#'>ALL</a></dd>
   <dd><a class="tab" id="Tab1" href="#" data-certiria='filter1'>filter1</a></dd>
   <dd><a class="tab" id="Tab2" href="#" data-certiria='filter1'>filter2</a></dd>
   <dd><a class="tab" id="Tab3" href="#" data-certiria='filter1'>filter3</a></dd> 
</dl>

function filterTab(cretiria, clickedTab) {
    $('#searchForm1').ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/sample/search?str=' + cretiria,
        beforeSend: function () {
            clickedTab.text('Filtering...');
            clickedTab.css({
                "font-size": "11px"
            });
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('.sample').html(html);
            clickedTab.text(cretiria);
            clickedTab.css({
                "font-size": "14px"
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Network Error..Please try again.');
        }
    });
}

$('.tab').live('click', function () {
    var dis = $(this);
    var str = $(this).data("certiria");
    filterTab(str, dis)
});
```

Instead of coping the same ajax request code again create a separate function.
Then use data elements inside that tabs to hold the required filter criteria.
then use one generic click function that retrieves that data element and sends it to the ajax function to manage the request.

Comment: Cheers, keep in mind that is always the case with reusable code components if there is a duplicate code extract it to a function...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` to delegate rather than `.live`.  Then, you can use pretty much the same method except like so:

```
$(".Tabs").on('click', 'dd', function () {
    var str = $(this).text();
    //...
});
```